How to export data into several Flat Files using Informatica Developer (Big Data Management)?
I have data from Hive table and I want to export the data into several flat files, partitioned by rows, into equal/almost equal number of rows on each target.
Is there any way to partition data into several flat files dynamically like:

output_01
output_02
output_03
and so on, with equal or almost equal number of rows on each target file using Informatica Developer (Big Data Management)?


I can describe how it should be done in PowerCenter or in Informatica Cloud, if you're using any of them.
Short answer is:

create File Name port in Traget Definition - this will make the dynamic file names possible
use Transaction Control transformation with TC_COMMIT_BEFORE flag anytime the desired amount of rows gets processed - this will close the current file and redirect writes to new file (with name specified in File Name port value). This will create multiple files as a result.

